# Decoding non-JSON response with RemoteData

Tags: http, elm

I would like to use RemoteData to represent some data that’s not JSON and I can’t figure out where to stick the custom decoder. I have these types:

```
Http.getString : String -> Request String
RemoteData.sendRequest : Request a -> Cmd (WebData a)
Foo.decode : String -> Result String (List Foo)
```

Now I would like to have a `ReceiveFoos (RemoteData String (List Foo))` message to receive the already decoded (or failed) response. How do I do that?

Or, in general, can I somehow supply my own `String -> Something` decoder to `Http.get`, similar to the JSON decoding case that’s supported out of the box?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`expectStringResponse`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http#expectStringResponse) to build up a custom request with a custom decoder.

For instance, here's a variation on `Http.get` which allows you to specify a decoder that receives the full string response body:

```elm
getStringResponse : String -> (Http.Response String -> Result String a) -> Http.Request a
getStringResponse url decoder =
  Http.request
    { method = "GET"
    , headers = []
    , url = url
    , body = Http.emptyBody
    , expect = Http.expectStringResponse decoder
    , timeout = Nothing
    , withCredentials = False
    }
```

(Notice that this looks a lot like the [implementation of the JSON version, `Http.get`](https://github.com/elm-lang/http/blob/1.0.0/src/Http.elm#L159-L169))